# How to stop converting known genre to number in id3v2 tag?

Tags: vb.net, save, taglib-sharp, id3v2

I'm on VB.NET 2012 Express, using the mono/taglib-sharp 2.0 library (Win7).

If I run this working code snippet to save 3 genres into the id3v2 tag of an existing mp3 track:

```
Dim ThreeGenresInStringArray() As String = {"Folk rock", "Bluegrass", "Indie folk"}
Dim MyTaglibMP3 As TagLib.File = TagLib.File.Create("C:\temp\I'm Alive.mp3")

MyTaglibMP3.Tag.Genres = ThreeGenresInStringArray

MyTaglibMP3.Save()
MyTaglibMP3.Dispose()
```

the second genre will be converted from the string 'Bluegrass' to the integer 89. If I look into this id3tag with a tool like Mp3tag, the genre will be shown as 'Folk rock/89/Indie folk'.

How can I stop taglib-sharp to convert "known" genres into numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line of code will turn off saving ID3v2 numeric genres for your entire application.

```
TagLib.Id3v2.Tag.UseNumericGenres = false;
```

Comment: Perfect! For those using VB.NET, just use    `TagLib.Id3v2.Tag.UseNumericGenres = False`